# How to pivot a dates table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a `containerID` number that has many dates. I have pivoted each date into a column using the code below. The problem is that each column has a set of three null values. I am trying to merge my four rows of the same container ID into one row with the dates on the four columns.

Example data:

```
    ContainerID MovementMilestone   MilestoneDate
    ---------------------------------------------
    ACCU4035970 Left Yard           2021-02-01
    ACCU4035970 Empty Return        2021-02-01
    ACCU4035970 Yard Arrival        2021-01-29
    ACCU4035970 Gate Out            2021-01-29
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    ContainerID,
    CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Gate Out' THEN MilestoneDate END AS 'mm_GateOut',
    CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Yard Arrival' THEN MilestoneDate END AS ' mm_YardArrival',
    CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Left Yard' THEN MilestoneDate END AS 'mm_LeftYard',
    CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Empty Return' THEN MilestoneDate END AS 'mm_EmptyReturn'
FROM 
    #movementmilestone
```

Output:

```
   ContainerID  mm_GateOut   mm_YardArrival mm_LeftYard mm_EmptyReturn
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACCU4035970  NULL         NULL           2021-02-01  NULL
   ACCU4035970  NULL         NULL           NULL        2021-02-01
   ACCU4035970  NULL         2021-01-29     NULL        NULL
   ACCU4035970  2021-01-29   NULL           NULL        NULL
```

I am aware of the PIVOT function on SQL Server but following examples from the internet has led me to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
         containerID,
         MovementMilestone,
         MilestoneDate
     FROM 
         #movementmilestone) AS #source
PIVOT 
    (MAX(MilestoneDate) FOR [MovementMilestone]
     IN ([GateOut], [YardArrival], [LeftYard], [EmptyReturn]))
    AS #alias
```

Output:

```
   ContainerID  GateOut YardArrival LeftYard    EmptyReturn
   ACCU4035970  NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: change the IN on the pivot and add spaces.   Values in MovementMilestone will be the columns names.   So change it to `IN ([Gate Out], [Yard Arrival], [Left Yard], [Empty Return])`

Comment: Thanks Tim Mylott and GrahamH, both solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
--OLD FASHIONED WAY <GRIN>

CREATE TABLE #movementmilestone(
   ContainerID       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
  ,MovementMilestone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,MilestoneDate     DATE  NOT NULL
 );
INSERT INTO #movementmilestone(ContainerID,MovementMilestone,MilestoneDate) VALUES ('ACCU4035970','Left','2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO #movementmilestone(ContainerID,MovementMilestone,MilestoneDate) VALUES ('ACCU4035970','Empty','2021-02-01');
INSERT INTO #movementmilestone(ContainerID,MovementMilestone,MilestoneDate) VALUES ('ACCU4035970','Yard','2021-01-29');
INSERT INTO #movementmilestone(ContainerID,MovementMilestone,MilestoneDate) VALUES ('ACCU4035970','Gate','2021-01-29');


SELECT
       ContainerID,
       MAX( CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Gate' THEN MilestoneDate END ) AS 'mm_GateOut',
       MAX (CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Yard' THEN MilestoneDate END ) AS ' mm_YardArrival',
       MAX( CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Left' THEN MilestoneDate END ) AS 'mm_LeftYard',
       MAX ( CASE WHEN MovementMilestone = 'Empty' THEN MilestoneDate END ) AS 'mm_EmptyReturn'
    FROM #movementmilestone
    GROUP BY ContainerID
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your `pivot` query is that you didn't provide the correct column names in the `IN` clause.

try the following:

```
select ContainerID, [Gate Out] as mm_GateOut, [Yard Arrival] as mm_YardArrival, [Left Yard] as mm_LeftYard, [Empty Return] as mm_EmptyReturn
from 
(
    select ContainerID, MovementMilestone, MilestoneDate
    from movementmilestone
)t
pivot
(
    max(MilestoneDate)
    for MovementMilestone in ([Left Yard], [Empty Return], [Yard Arrival], [Gate Out])
)pvt;
```

Please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e40d63889fd64c22b4047519ac50e6d)**.